# How can I add a dimmer to a bathroom switch that also turns the fan on?

Tags: wiring, lighting, exhaust-fan

I would like to add a dimmer switch to the bathroom. The switch currently turns on a extractor fan with a timer. It is connected via an isolation switch.

I understand I cannot run the fan on a dimmer switch, so wondered if it was possible to make these independent of one another.

So instead of one switch I have two switches, one for the fan and a dimmer module for the lights.

Is this possible?

[image: Wiring 1]
[image: Wiring 2]

Comment: Where on the planet are you, and can you post photos of the inside of the fan/light junction box?

Comment: I'm in the UK, and thats all I have access to at the moment. Aren't all the junctions happening here?

Comment: What am I looking at here?  Why is there the usual brown/blue in your twin-and-earth, **and also black**?  Black is the *second hot* color, so this isn't twin-and-earth, it's triple, at least for 2 of the 4 cables coming into the box.   Why is the brown and black double-tapped on the switch?  That makes the wires redundant.  Is it possible brown is the light, black is the fan, and binding them to the same terminals of this switch is *why* they switch together?